# Connecting network gear directly to electrical line

Tags: electrical, wiring, outdoor

I’m installing multiple PoE networking switches on a pier, but I’m not sure the best route for plugging them in. There are only a few existing plugs on the dock but they aren’t located near where these switches will be installed. Plus, I don’t want people to be able to unplug any of them since they’ll be powering security cameras.

All the electrical wires are contained within conduit piping, and I’m not sure what the best way to open them up is.

I’m hoping to find a way to either cut the power cables at the ends and connect them directly to the electrical cables or install a single enclosed outlet and plug them in there. I’m open to any methods and prefer to go the safest, easiest, and most used route.

Here’s an example of what the electrical line is enclosed in throughout the pier:

[image: Electrical pipe]

And here’s a picture of the absolute mess that I’m hoping to clean up:

[image: Networking Box]

Comment: Is that a *cable* running up the conduit to the top of the pole, or a set of *individual wires*?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel From what I can tell in the picture and what I remember, it looks like a single cable that exits the conduit and enters the light. I’ll double check next time I’m down there.

Comment: Is there a junction box as the base of the light pole, for that matter? And where do you want to put these PoE injectors?

Comment: Is this whole area behind 8ma GFCI protection?

Comment: At least it’s all wood and not a steel structure pier, but this is a mess.  Personally I’d not locate PoE switches and/or injectors out here.  Put those inside, run just a single Ethernet cable to each camera.

Comment: Any updates on this @Ladinn

Comment: This was so long ago, I also want to know what's happened in the meantime!